# The index ranging in Matlab matrices

Tags: matlab

I want to know what this line of code does.

`ind_x = [1,3:5:size(paths,2)]`

What would `ind_x` contain after this line? I already know that `size(paths,2)` means the size of second dimension of `paths` matrix.

Comment: This is one of those cases where trying the command out on a known test array would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3:5:size(path,2)` returns a vector which starts from `3` to `size(path,2)` with steps `5`. For example, if `size(path,2)` is equal to `20`, the result would be:

```
ind_x

  [1 3 8 13 18]
```

As you can see it counts from 3 to `size(path,2)` with step size `5` (`3, 8, 13, ...`).